# Add button between two tableView cells

Tags: swift

Need to add (just once) a button between first and second row of tableview

like this

[image]

how to do this ?

```
cell.clipsToBounds = false
cell.addButton.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: getHeightOfRow() - 300, width: 50, height:  50 )
```

the button didn’t go beyond the cell border

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest option would be to disable **Clip To Bounds** on your `UITableViewCell`. Then, using auto layout (or just `CGRect` if your are using code) set it up so the button is at the position you want it to be. With **Clip To Bounds** disabled, you can place UI elements that are subviews of a parent, outside the parent and they will still show up.

To disable **Clip To Bounds** using code, you can use the following variable on your `UITableViewCell`:

```swift
var clipsToBounds: Bool { get set }
```

```swift
let cell: UITableViewCell

// ----------

cell.clipsToBounds = false
```

More info: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622415-clipstobounds

Or, you can set the property in the **Attributes Inspector**:

[image: Clip To Bounds using Attributes Inspector]

Comment: ty for answer, but he does not work, can u help me to find the error ? 
            `cell.clipsToBounds = false
            cell.addButton.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: getHeightOfRow() - 300, width: 50, height:  50 )`

the button did not go beyond the cell border

Comment: What value does `getHeightOfRow() - 300` get as result? Have you tried just passing `getHeightOfRow()` only?

Answer (score 1):

- You can merge two cells
- You can add subview to scroll and in scrollviewdelegete move it with cell by frame
- You can put it with layout and remove clipToBounds property(for preventing cut) and move to front if needed

Also for single creation You can use 'lazy var' in vc and add subview inside it